# What are the consequences of disabling or enabling APM on a (e.g. seagate) drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm trying to understand the difference between enabling APM vs disabling APM (Advanced Power Management) on a drive. (Enterprise/Desktop class)

Due to a lot of information with a different perspective on this question, I'm taking it here.

Comment: You mean other than increased power usage?

Comment: I'm looking to understand from multiple perspectives - CPU usage, power usage, drive health, etc